# I can't find the correct answer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

A block of mass 4kg is pressed against the wall by a force of 80 N. Determine  the value  of frictional force  and blocks acceleration (Static frictional  coefficient =0.2,kinetic  frictional coefficient
 =0.15)(force applied at 37°with horizontal)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Resolve force vector $P$ and draw the FBD for the block.

Remember, normal will be equal to component of $P$ in horizontal direction.

Determine whether object will accelerate, if yes, then plug in the values in $F=ma$.

[image: FBD of the block]

Comment: While perhaps providing hints to get OP started is fine as an answer, we generally do not provide solutions to homework-type questions on this site. It defeats the purpose of OP going through the homework himself and learning relevant analytical and deductive skills. Furthermore, there is no advantage for this site as the question and answer is only useful to this specific user.

Comment: @nluigi Okay, I edited it.

Comment: An alternative website for such questions is physicsproblems.nfshost.com, but you are still expected to show some effort.